# Is it possible to produce a list of syntactic rules for a language?

Tags: syntax, computational-linguistics, french, parsing, evolution

I recently started a new job as an applied linguist engineer and one of the first tasks I was ask to do was to provide a list of syntactic rules that can produce French sentences (for an implementation to a system).

I'm wondering if it's possible, knowing that a language is not static but evolving all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes you can, especially if what you want is a subset of French sentences. You will need more rules for a greater subset.

The decision as to when that subset is large enough, is with you. Eventually your rules may also generate sentences which are only marginally grammatical. It is very difficult to scope this problem precisely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, the generated sentence must be grammatical but if we take a closer look, we'll notice that in spoken production or in Poetry, wrong coordinations are often used between two elements which can result in zeugmas.
I have to take into account these nongrammatical sentences.